# How to get list of suburbs in Australia using Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my project I want users to select an Australian Suburb. The form having an auto-suggest field when user types the Suburb it needs to suggest matching suburbs to the query. The following screenshot show what I need exactly.

Can someone know what is the Google Maps API I should use? I have gone through the Google documentation but I couldn't find it yet. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Suburbs? You mean localities?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: yes, localities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete) with the `types` option on `(regions)` or `(cities)` depending on what you want.

You can also use `componentRestrictions` to limit the results to a specific area or country, Australia in your case.

```js
function initialize() {

  var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'AU'
      }
    });

  ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {

    var place = ac.getPlace();

    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // Alert the selected place
    window.alert("You selected: '" + place.formatted_address + "'");
  });
}
```

```css
#autocomplete {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
<input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
```

Note that you need to load the places library in your API call:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initialize" async defer></script>`